# Numerically solve non-linear system using Newton and trust-region strategies

Tags: nonlinear-system, python

I want to numerically solve a matrix system such as
$$
A(u)u=f(u)
$$
where $A,f$ are non-linear. One of the ways of going around it is to use some Global Newton with an adaptive trust region method. Is there any Python library dedicated to solving this kind of problem? Thanks!